# How to use spreadtab inside form for this type of tabular?

Tags: forms, spreadtab

[image]I would like to automate the column total using spreadtab in the table but couldn't do. Please help.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
    \usepackage[left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{array} 
    \usepackage{multirow} 
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{spreadtab}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{form}
    \def\arraystretch{1.5}{
    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.0cm}|p{4.8cm}|p{7.3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|}} \cline{4-7}
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Group \#1}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Group \#2}} \\ \cline{4-7}
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \textbf{Student 1} & \textbf{Student 2} & \textbf{Student 1} & \textbf{Student 2} \\ \hline  
   \textbf{S.No.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Criteria}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Sub-Criteria}} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=2.4cm,combo,default=,name=group1name1]{}{17MST1001   , 17MST1002 , 17MST1003 , 17MST1004 , 17MST1005 , 17MST1006 , 17MST1008,    17MST1009,  17MST1010,  17MST1011,  17MST1012,  17MST1013,  17MST1014,  17MST1015,  17MST1017,  17MST1018,  17MST1019,  17MST1020,  17MST1021,  17MST1022,  17MST1023,  17MST1024,  17MST1025,  17MST1026,  17MST1027,  17MST1028,  17MST1029,  17MST1030,  17MST1031,  17MST1032,  17MST1033,  17MST1034,  17MST1035,  17MST1036,  17MST1037,  17MST1038,  17MST1039,  17MST1040,  17MST1041,  17MST1042,  17MST1043,  17MST1044,  17MST1045,  17MST1046,  17MST1047,  17MST1048,  17MST1049,  17MST1050,  17MST1051,  17MST1052,  17MST1053,  17MST1054} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=2.4cm,combo,default=,name=group1name2]{}{17MST1001    , 17MST1002 , 17MST1003 , 17MST1004 , 17MST1005 , 17MST1006 , 17MST1008,    17MST1009,  17MST1010,  17MST1011,  17MST1012,  17MST1013,  17MST1014,  17MST1015,  17MST1017,  17MST1018,  17MST1019,  17MST1020,  17MST1021,  17MST1022,  17MST1023,  17MST1024,  17MST1025,  17MST1026,  17MST1027,  17MST1028,  17MST1029,  17MST1030,  17MST1031,  17MST1032,  17MST1033,  17MST1034,  17MST1035,  17MST1036,  17MST1037,  17MST1038,  17MST1039,  17MST1040,  17MST1041,  17MST1042,  17MST1043,  17MST1044,  17MST1045,  17MST1046,  17MST1047,  17MST1048,  17MST1049,  17MST1050,  17MST1051,  17MST1052,  17MST1053,  17MST1054} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=2.4cm,combo,default=,name=group2name1]{}{17MST1001    , 17MST1002 , 17MST1003 , 17MST1004 , 17MST1005 , 17MST1006 , 17MST1008,    17MST1009,  17MST1010,  17MST1011,  17MST1012,  17MST1013,  17MST1014,  17MST1015,  17MST1017,  17MST1018,  17MST1019,  17MST1020,  17MST1021,  17MST1022,  17MST1023,  17MST1024,  17MST1025,  17MST1026,  17MST1027,  17MST1028,  17MST1029,  17MST1030,  17MST1031,  17MST1032,  17MST1033,  17MST1034,  17MST1035,  17MST1036,  17MST1037,  17MST1038,  17MST1039,  17MST1040,  17MST1041,  17MST1042,  17MST1043,  17MST1044,  17MST1045,  17MST1046,  17MST1047,  17MST1048,  17MST1049,  17MST1050,  17MST1051,  17MST1052,  17MST1053,  17MST1054} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=2.4cm,combo,default=,name=group2name2]{}{17MST1001    , 17MST1002 , 17MST1003 , 17MST1004 , 17MST1005 , 17MST1006 , 17MST1008,    17MST1009,  17MST1010,  17MST1011,  17MST1012,  17MST1013,  17MST1014,  17MST1015,  17MST1017,  17MST1018,  17MST1019,  17MST1020,  17MST1021,  17MST1022,  17MST1023,  17MST1024,  17MST1025,  17MST1026,  17MST1027,  17MST1028,  17MST1029,  17MST1030,  17MST1031,  17MST1032,  17MST1033,  17MST1034,  17MST1035,  17MST1036,  17MST1037,  17MST1038,  17MST1039,  17MST1040,  17MST1041,  17MST1042,  17MST1043,  17MST1044,  17MST1045,  17MST1046,  17MST1047,  17MST1048,  17MST1049,  17MST1050,  17MST1051,  17MST1052,  17MST1053,  17MST1054} \\ \hline  
    1. & \multirow{2}{*}{Presentation (30\%)} & Oral Presentation Skill (15\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box1]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7}
    2. &  & Visual Aid used (15\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box2]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \hline 
    3. & \multirow{2}{*}{Work  Accomplished (40\%)} & Quality of Work Done (20\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box3]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7}
   4. &  & Completion of Work (20\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box4]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \hline 
   5. & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Asnwering the Queries (10\%)} & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box5]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \hline 
   6. & \multirow{2}{*}{Documentation (20\%)} & Content of the Report (10\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box6]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-7}
   7. &  & Report Preparation (Formatting) (10\%) & \ChoiceMenu[print,height=0.2cm,width=1.5cm,combo,default=,name=box7]{}{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} & & & \\ \hline 
  & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\textbf{Grand Total} (Out of 70)} & sum(d4:d10) & & & \\ \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\textbf{Percentage}} & & & & \\ \hline
    \end{spreadtab}}
    \end{form}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: It won't work. spreadtab calculates the values when the pdf is created, but the values from the form are only known at use. You need another form field and javascript to update it. See e.g. the eforms manual, eformman.pdf.

Comment: Thank You @UlrikeFischer . I am aware of this but was little desperate to find if there is any other way exist.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer When I save this form, for every save I give, it produces new file (i.e, asking to save it new .pdfs), is there anyway that we can update all the saves in the single pdfs.